# Htaccess Rewrite Part of the url but keep the rest

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Sorry but I just can not find the answer

I would like to change

http://www.domain.com/video.php?id=ALWAYS-A-NUMBER/ALWAYS-A-TITLE
to
http://www.domain.com/video/ALWAYS-A-NUMBER/ALWAYS-A-TITLE

So far I am using the code below but it also removes /ALWAYS-A-TITLE so I end up with "This-bit-is-ok/video/94015"

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /video.php\?id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /video/%1? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)$ /video.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Can anyone see why the end is missing please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /video.php\?id=([0-9]+)/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /video/%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /video.php?id=$1/$2 [L]
```

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you so much for your really fast reply, It works perfectly. I gave up after trying for 2 hours ! Thank you so much for helping.